# Change Magento Shipping Method from 'Custom' to Courier's Name

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

at the moment we only use a single courier 'Australia Post'. When we go to Order list view, select an order, paste in the tracking number and then go to 'Actions>Ship Selected' the customer receives an email saying the Carrier is 'Custom Value'. Where and how can I change the default carrier value from 'Custom Value' to 'Australia Post'?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What shipping method are you using?

Comment: Australia Post eParcel, but it's not like there's a section in the backend of Magento for this. Effectively we're just filling out a custom name and sending an email with a tracking number. Does that help?

Comment: Which shipping method are you using, in the admin side shipping methods?

Comment: Hi, yes, we go to orders, click the checkbox next to the order and then select Actions>Ship Selected

Comment: You can either, modify the translation for 'Custom Value' in the sales module, or you can create a new shipping carrier config.